# Keeping a file locked between open and save with EPPLUS

Tags: c#, epplus

Just looking for some advice for the best way to open an existing excel file, carry out some process on the data and then save it again while prevent others making edits to the excel file between my load and save.

I think I'm best using the `FileStream` approach.

If I close the stream them immediately call `File.WriteAllBytes` the file is saved. However, if I try and get the byte array then write the stream before closing the stream the file doesn't save.  I know the `GetAsByteArray()` closes the package but why would that prevent me writing a `FileStream`?

```cs
using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
    {
        package.Load(stream);

        //DO MY LOGIC STUFF

        //byte[] data = package.GetAsByteArray();
        //stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        stream.Close();
        File.WriteAllBytes(_fileName, package.GetAsByteArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you write the file back using the same stream? Just set the length, and then write the bytes straight to `stream`. You don't need to explicitly `Close` it if you have `using`.

Comment: The approach is risky for multiple reasons.  Rename the file first.

Comment: @HansPassant.  Why so risky?  What process would you recommend?  Ultimately the file has to end up the same name it started with.

Comment: File operations fail, sooner or later.  By overwriting the file, you risk the user losing their spreadsheet.  They won't be happy.  If you rename the file first then there's still a copy of the original that you can rename back.  And your problem is solved as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if I try and get the byte array then write the stream before closing the stream the file doesn't save. I know the `GetAsByteArray()` closes the package but why would that prevent me writing a FileStream?

It's nothing to do with the `GetAsByteArray()` function, it's because the stream is still holding the file open, preventing another function from opening a new handle to it and writing it.

You need to reuse the stream you have already.

```cs
using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
using (var stream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
    package.Load(stream);

    //DO MY LOGIC STUFF

    byte[] data = package.GetAsByteArray();

    stream.Position = 0;  // seek back to the beginning
    stream.SetLength(data.Length);
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: Oh that was a schoolboy error!.   Thanks